# Is there a way to disable 'iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *' automatic creation?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

Xcode automatically creates provisioning profiles for any app.

In my case, I have tons of apps in a single project. And I'm forced to create a development and app store profile manually for every single app.

I want to disable this automatic creation, it's not helping me.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend never to add your account to Xcode. This prevents it from creating insane numbers of profiles. It also prevents it from altering existing profiles that may be shared with other team members.

Comment: This is the only way. But sometime you may need to add your account, to get things synced properly, as profiles tend not to work.